# shell script is not working in cron job | docker

Tags: docker, shell, cron

I'm trying to automate a postgres database backup which is running in docker,

```
#!/bin/bash
POSTGRES_USERNAME="XXX"
CONTAINER_NAME="YYY"
DB_NAME="ZZZ"
BACKUP="/tmp/backup/${DB_NAME}.sql.gz"
docker exec -it -u ${POSTGRES_USERNAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME} pg_dump -d ${DB_NAME} |
gzip -c > ${BACKUP}  
exit
```

if i run this manually, i can get the backup, but if i schedule the script into cronjob means, i got empty folder,

can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a `$PATH` or using the full paths to `docker` and `gzip`?

Comment: The difference may come from the user that is used to schedule `cron` jobs that may be different from the the user involved in the manual test. If the two users are different you have to check if they have the same rights for example, all users are not able to invoke docker.

Comment: Hello @Biffen thank you so much for your response yes i have tried with that too. but no luck, i tested the above script with the below PATH, but it backups empty directory 

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin:/bin/date:/usr/bin/aws:/bin/gzip:/usr/bin/pg_dump:/usr/bin/docker

Comment: Hello @Romain thank you so much for your response, i agree with your point but i scheduled cronjob with root user

Comment: @Antonynixson cron usually sends an email if a job writes anything to STDERR. See if you can find that email, it should help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello everyone thank you so much for your immediate response, i think
> i have fixed my issue.

Cronjob failed due to --interactive mode

```
docker exec -it -u ${POSTGRES_USERNAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME} pg_dump -d ${DB_NAME} | gzip -c > ${BACKUP}
```

Removed i --interactive from shell script, then it's works perfect.

```
docker exec -t -u ${POSTGRES_USERNAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME} pg_dump -d ${DB_NAME} | gzip -c > ${BACKUP}
```